# C++Builder TMouseWheelEvent compiler error

Tags: c++builder, tscrollbox

No matter how I attempt to use it, I cannot dynamically create a `TScrollBox` and assign an `OnMouseWheelEvent` handler to it. I get the following compiler error:

> E2034 Cannot convert 'void (_fastcall * (_closure )(TObject *,TShiftState,int,TPoint &,bool &))(TObject *,TShiftState,int,TPoint &,bool &)' to 'TMouseWheelEvent'

My declaration for the `OnMouseWheelEvent` handler is correct (as far as I can tell):

```
....
TScrollBox *sb = new TScrollBox(funnelCharts);
sb->Top = 5000;
sb->Parent = funnelCharts;
sb->Align = alClient;
sb->Height = funnelCharts->ClientHeight;
sb->OnMouseWheel = scrollEvent;
....

// --------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm1::scrollEvent(TObject *Sender, TShiftState Shift, int WheelDelta, TPoint &MousePos, bool &Handled)
{
    TScrollBox *scrollbox = dynamic_cast<TScrollBox*>(Sender);
    if (scrollbox)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < Mouse->WheelScrollLines; i++)
        {
            if (WheelDelta > 0)
            {
                scrollbox->Perform(WM_VSCROLL, SB_LINEUP, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                scrollbox->Perform(WM_VSCROLL, SB_LINEDOWN, 0);
            }
        }
        scrollbox->Perform(WM_VSCROLL, SB_ENDSCROLL, 0);
        Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a *compiler* error, not a *linker* error.

Look at the actual declaration of `TMouseWheelEvent` in `Controls.hpp`.  Your `scrollEvent()` method does not match what is actually declared, otherwise you would not be getting the error.

Depending on whether you are compiling for 32-bit or 64-bit, `TMouseWheelEvent` (specifically, its `MousePos` parameter) is declared differently:

32-bit:

```
typedef void __fastcall (__closure *TMouseWheelEvent)(System::TObject* Sender, System::Classes::TShiftState Shift, int WheelDelta, const System::Types::TPoint &MousePos, bool &Handled);
```

64-bit:

```
typedef void __fastcall (__closure *TMouseWheelEvent)(System::TObject* Sender, System::Classes::TShiftState Shift, int WheelDelta, System::Types::TPoint MousePos, bool &Handled);
```

The reason for this is BCC32 and BCC64 differ in how they pass around 8-byte struct types (like `TPoint`).  This difference is documented on Embarcadero's DocWiki:

[Events with Structures or Sets of 5-8 Bytes Are Not Valid for BCC64](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Release_Notes#Events_with_Structures_or_Sets_of_5-8_Bytes_Are_Not_Valid_for_BCC64)

Other event types affected by this difference include `TGetSiteInfoEvent`, `TMouseWheelUpDownEvent`, and `TContextPopupEvent`.

To fix this, you will have to `#ifdef` your code as documented:

```
class TForm1 : public TForm
{
    ...
    #ifndef _WIN64
    void __fastcall scrollEvent(TObject* Sender, TShiftState Shift, int WheelDelta, const TPoint &MousePos, bool &Handled);
    #else
    void __fastcall scrollEvent(TObject* Sender, TShiftState Shift, int WheelDelta, TPoint MousePos, bool &Handled);
    #endif
    ...
};

...

#ifndef _WIN64
void __fastcall TForm1::scrollEvent(TObject* Sender, TShiftState Shift, int WheelDelta, const TPoint &MousePos, bool &Handled)
#else
void __fastcall TForm1::scrollEvent(TObject* Sender, TShiftState Shift, int WheelDelta, TPoint MousePos, bool &Handled)
#endif
{
    ...
}
```

Or, a little cleaner approach:

```
class TForm1 : public TForm
{
    ...
    void __fastcall scrollEvent(
        TObject* Sender, TShiftState Shift, int WheelDelta,
        #ifndef _WIN64
        const TPoint &MousePos,
        #else
        TPoint MousePos,
        #endif
        bool &Handled);
    ...
};

...

void __fastcall TForm1::scrollEvent(TObject* Sender, TShiftState Shift, int WheelDelta,
    #ifndef _WIN64
    const TPoint &MousePos,
    #else
    TPoint MousePos,
    #endif
    bool &Handled)
{
    ...
}
```

Or, even cleaner:

```
#ifndef _WIN64
#define SAFE_5TO8_PARAM(type, name) const type &name
#else
#define SAFE_5TO8_PARAM(type, name) type name
#endif

class TForm1 : public TForm
{
    ...
    void __fastcall scrollEvent(TObject* Sender, TShiftState Shift, int WheelDelta, SAFE_5TO8_PARAM(TPoint, MousePos), bool &Handled);
    ...
};

...

void __fastcall TForm1::scrollEvent(TObject* Sender, TShiftState Shift, int WheelDelta, SAFE_5TO8_PARAM(TPoint, MousePos), bool &Handled)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: So it was just the const that I was missing (for 32-bit).

Thank you!